# Debug a complex T-SQL procedure on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very complex T-SQL procedure about 2000 lines (I didn't develop it). I was asked to fix some bugs on it. I tried some methods as:

- using of debug option that I found in `SQL Server Management Studio`
- using of "PRINT" statement to watch the variables

My question:
What's the best method to debug a procedure like this?

Comment: Review statements from top down, step by step fashion.  Depending on the bugs, using Profiler to monitor what is actually executing (stored procedures and TSQL) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Start by refactoring the procedure into multiple smaller procedures that can be tested and debugged in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to print statements, you may be able to use the [`output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause in most of your queries (including inserts, updates & deletes) so you can see intermediate results and without disrupting the flow of the procedure. Exampls:

Delete statements:

```
delete [tbl]
output deleted.*
 where [something] = 'stuff';
```

Insert statements:

```
insert [tbl]
output inserted.*
values (42, 'things');
```

Update statements:

```
update [tb]
output deleted.*, -- Original values
       inserted.* -- Updated values
   set [something] = 'poopen'
 where [id] = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In SQL Server 2008 we can make use of the "Debug >> Start Debugging". For prior versions I have made use of Visual Studio - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet1b7by(VS.80).aspx
2. Make use of SQL Profiler
3. PRINT Stmt (by having a parameter to decide to print or not)

These are to be used and tested in non-PROD environments only.